# Pig Latin converter

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working on an exercise which involves converting the sentence "The quick brown fox" to “Hetay uickqay rownbay oxfay”

```
def translate(sent)
  sent = sent.downcase
  vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  words = sent.split(' ')
  result = []

  words.each_with_index do |word, i|
    translation = ''
    qu = false
    if vowels.include? word[0]
      translation = word + 'ay'
      result.push(translation)
    else
      word = word.split('')
      count = 0
      word.each_with_index do |char, index|
        if vowels.include? char
          # handle words that start with 'qu'
            if char == 'u' and translation[-1] == 'q'
            qu = true
            translation = words[i][count..words[i].length] + translation + 'ay'
            result.push(translation)
            next
          end
          break
        else
          # handle words with 'qu' in middle
          if char == 'q' and translation[i-1] == 'u'
            qu = true
            translation = words[i][count +1..words[i].length] + 'ay'
            result.push(translation)
            next
          else
            translation += char
          end
          count += 1
        end
      end
      # translation of consonant words without "qu"
      if not qu
        translation = words[i][count..words[i].length] + translation + 'ay'
        result.push(translation)
      end
    end

  end
  result.join(' ')
end

puts translate("The quick brown fox")
```

However, I'm getting "ethay uickqay ownbray oxfay" instead of “Hetay uickqay rownbay oxfay”.

Where are the areas that needs correction? I couldn't pinpoint the problem. Could you show me the solution?

Comment: Your code is hard to reason about. The reasons for this include: one long method, nested if-expressions, mutations of variables (`word` contains different kinds of data at different points in time), bad indentation. Please consider doing the following: split all meaningful tasks into separate methods, don't change the contents of variables unnecessarily,

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very procedural and complex way of going about this.  I'm not sure what your rules for checking `q` and `u` are for, since the [pig latin translation rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) make no mention of `qu` as a special case:

A far simpler way is to split the sentence into an array of words, and transform each word as required:

```
def translate(sent)
  translation = sent.split(' ').map do |w|
    vowels = %w(a e i o u)
    word = w.downcase.split('')

    if vowels.include? word[0]
      "#{word}way"
    else
      "%s%say" % [word[1..-1], word[0]]
    end
  end

  translation.join(' ').capitalize
end

puts translate("The quick brown fox")
# outputs Hetay uickqay rownbay oxfay
```

And, for 1.9 and likely above:

```
def translate(sent)
  translation = sent.split(' ').map do |w|
    vowels = %w(a e i o u)
    word = w.downcase.split('')

    if vowels.include? word[0]
      "#{word.join}way"
    else
      "%s%say" % [word[1..-1].join, word[0]]
    end
  end

  translation.join(' ').capitalize
end

puts translate("The quick brown fox")
```

Obviously, both of these are examples and can likely be made far better with work.  But they serve to illustrate the point.

This makes use of `map` and `join`, and can probably be optimised further.  The key difference between this method and yours is that you are attempting to build up a map of the translation iteratively, when you probably do not need to.  Use the enumeration functions, they are part of what makes the functional programming style more expressive.  Learn to think "how do I permute this data set to get my desired response" as opposed to "What steps do I need to perform to get my desired response".

Comment: ["h", "e"]tay ["u", "i", "c", "k"]qay ["r", "o", "w", "n"]bay ["o", "x"]fay. This is what your code generated on the command prompt. @mcfinnigan

Comment: @iJava I see, difference between ruby 1.8 and 1.9.  One moment.

Comment: Really appreciate your help.